# Comparative Analysis of Object Recognition or Tracking Methods with Multiple Kinects

Tags: kinect, image-recognition, point-cloud-library

First of all, I have looked into the list of all branches of StackExchange, and this seems to be the one best suited for this question.

I am looking for a comparative analysis (can be both theoretical and implementation-oriented) between various popular methods of object recognition and tracking using a Microsoft Kinect 360. These methods do not have to include specialised Kinect API features like hand gesture recognition or skeleton tracking. Could you point me to some technical literature that tackles this subject? I have found quite a few papers that talk about doing object detection and training based on the PCL library. I have also found some papers on using just the RGB image of the Kinect to do classic object tracking. But to put things into perspective, I want to know which method gives good performance and is less challenging to implement when a set of Kinects (possibly with overlapping projection cones) is used to do object recognition and/or tracking.

In my opinion, building a unified point cloud to analyse and label the objects to recognise/classify them using multiple Kinects (assuming I have multiple BUSes) would have too high processing overhead. Would it be a viable alternative to do foreground extraction on the depth images separately and then somehow identify duplicates?